# Estimate SD using pass rate and median of large-scale exam

Tags: r, normal-distribution, estimation, standard-deviation

I have a list of medians and pass rates for national exams (scores go from 0 to 100) and need the SD. I do not have access to the individual scores. I am assuming normal distribution.

How do estimate the SD knowing only the median and the % of students that passed, i.e. had a score of 60% or higher?

My current solution is to brute-force it (generate samples and change the sd until you get a pass rate that's close enough) but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
library(data.table)
library(fGarch) 
exams <- data.table(note=rsnorm(n=10000, mean=71.2, sd=12.5)) #change the sd 
nrow(exams[note >=60]) / 100 #...until this is close enough to the pass rate
```

Edit : here is a mathematical solution but I am not sure if I got it right.

```
sd = abs( (median - 60) / qnorm(fail.rate) )
```

Comment: Since it's mathematically impossible for the distribution to be exactly normal, the solution actually is a little tricky: perhaps it has to be a *truncated* normal, cut off at the endpoints $0$ and $100$?  If you're sure extremely few people scored near $0$ or $100$, then the straightforward calculation of the sd will be fine. If you use the correct formula, you shouldn't need `abs`!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The solution I went for was to simulate truncated data with the specified pass rate and median, then calculate the sd of the simulation.